# Convergence of $\frac{1}{1+x^n}$ on $(0,1)$ shows inconsistency

Tags: analysis

(Pointwise) Convergence of $y_n (x) = \frac{1}{1+x^n}$ on $(0,1)$ shows inconsistency.

One can work it out and show that it indeed converges to $1$ as $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} x^n = 0$.

What if we set $x = 3^{\frac{-1}{n}}$? Don't we get a contradiction?

Comment: I don’t think the argument can depend on n.

Answer (score 1):

When you have to prove that a sequence of functions $f_n(x)$ is Pointwise convergent in a given set, for instance in an interval $I$ you have:

1. Choose a general point of $x_0\in I$ and keep it fixed.
2. Prove that $
   \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } f_n \left( {x_0 } \right) = f(x_0 )
   $
   where $f(x_0)$ is a real number dependent from $x_0$.
   In your reasoning you did not all that, since you choose $x=3^{-1/n}$ and this is not a fixed point in $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

There's no contradiction if you look at $y_n (x_n) = f_n(x_n) = f_n(3^{-1/n})$. This is not the same as taking $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} y_n(x)$ for a particular fixed $x$.

Perhaps you contradict the claim that the sequence of functions converges uniformly.

Comment: Right. The pointwise doesn't work that way, the $\epsilon$ doesn't depend on $x$, it's the other way round. The $x$ should've been fixed to make sense out of that. Now, using the definition of uniform convergence (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence), it seems like $\displaystyle\sup_{x \in (0,1)} |y_n (x) - y(x)| \geq |y_n (3^{-\frac{1}{n}}) - 1| \geq \frac{2}{3}$. This cannot converge to $0$ while we all know that $\frac{1}{x^n+1}$ is uniformly convergent on the interval